# What is good embeddable java application server

Tags: java, rest, soap, application-server

I need a recommendation for a good embeddable Java application server that is small, fast, lightweight and supports SOAP/REST and preferebly summat with a  decent licence like Apache or MIT, i.e. no heavy duty copyleft.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick respone. Seems a solid wee server with apache licence. Excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need any J2EE functionality beyond Servlets, then Jetty is a good embedded choice. However, if you intend to use extended J2EE functionality such as EJBs, JPA, JMX and ease of administration is important to you then, you will need to go beyond an embedded solution and explore Glassfish etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) is probably the most popular embeddable java application server.

Comment: Jetty is not a java application server. It is an web server & servlet container.

Answer (score 1):

Why not [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/)?